# How to use Linq to find dates in listed but not in another

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list objects: one describes a list of shifts and another that describes a list of sick leave.

What I am trying to do is compare the two lists and return a result that just gives a list of sick leave, where the dates in sick-leave is not in the list of shifts.

I have written this code, but it does not return a list:

```
var nonAvailableDates =availability
   .Where(a=>! shiftDay.Any(b=>b.ShiftDate.Date == a.StartPeriod.Date)).ToList();
```

Can someone please show me where I have gone wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I just get an empty list. I was expecting at least one element, which I know is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the set difference operation, which is the Except() method in LINQ (will give you all elements in first collection that are not in second):

```
List<DateTime> shifts = new List<DateTime>{ DateTime.Parse("1/1/2014"), DateTime.Parse("1/2/2014")};
List<DateTime> sickLeaves = new List<DateTime>{DateTime.Parse("1/1/2014"), DateTime.Parse("1/3/2014")};

var sickLeavesThatAreNotAlsoShifts = sickLeaves.Except(shifts); // contains only 1/3/2014
```

EDIT: Give this a shot. We're basically joining and then taking the items which don't have any match.

```
var sickLeavesNotInShifts = from sickLeave in sickLeaves
                            join shift in shifts on sickLeave.StartPeriod equals shift.ShiftDate into joinedShifts
                            from js in joinedShifts.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where js == null
                            select sickLeave;
```

Note: This is asymptotically better than doing nested searches, since join internally implements a hash join, which is O(m+n) (m and n being the counts for the two collections).

Comment: I don't think this would work, because the two objects are different. The dates are properties which I am linking on

Comment: Can you show the class and properties you're comparing? Hard to decipher from your example.

Comment: Shifts has shiftdate, location, employee, comment, starttime and finishtime. Whereas availability is nonavailabledate, type, comment, starttime and finishtime.

Comment: I gave it a shot but I got back an Ienmurable which I couldn't see the results

Comment: @Andy5 - do a `.ToList()` on the result.

Comment: Leaving the js=null returned nothing where it should have returned one result. Removing it did return a result, and trying it further returned a result when it should not have returned a result. So the results are the wrong way round.

Comment: Can you post your original data set, where you expect a result of one date back?

Comment: It will be too difficult to do that

Comment: I would write some small test cases then to verify the code, and double check my assumptions about the code returning one result.